# How to group on multiple fields including nested eager columns

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eager-loading

I have some carts, products and users.
I try to get statistics like number of carts per user. And here are my models:

- user.php

  ```
  class User {
      public function products()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'user_id');
      }
  }
  ```
- cart.php

  ```
  class Cart {

      public function products()
      {
         return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'cart_id');
      }     
  }
  ```
- product.php

  ```
  class Product {

      public function user()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
      }

      public function cart()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Cart::class, 'cart_id');
      }      
  }
  ```

Here is my query:

```
$query = Cart::query()
        ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($filter) {
            $query->where('whatever', $filter);
        })
        ->join('product', 'product.cart_id', '=', 'cart.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'product.user_id')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->select('users.id as user_id')
        ->select('users.name')
        ->selectRaw('count(cart.id) as numberOfCarts')
        ->selectRaw('SUM(price)')
        ->orderBy('users.name')
        ->get();
```

What I get is number of products per user, but I want number of carts per user. when I try to group using *cart.id* like `groupBy(['user.id', 'cart.id'])`, it is worse: I get several times the same user and at each time the number of products in cart. And this total gives the same as total of number of carts get previously.

I have added jointure because I don't make it work by trying grouping on nested eager relationship. So I make it simplier.

How to fix grouping to count users carts and not their products ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `count()` counts the number of records returned [by your MySQL query](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_count.asp), so if you're looking at 20 rows all with the same `cart.id`, it's still going to count all 20 of them.

You can reduce this to what you want by only counting unique `cart.id`s with [distinct](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_distinct.asp):

```php
$query = Cart::query()
        ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($filter) {
            $query->where('whatever', $filter);
        })
        ->join('product', 'product.cart_id', '=', 'cart.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'product.user_id')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->select('users.id as user_id')
        ->select('users.name')
        ->selectRaw('count(distinct cart.id) as numberOfCarts') // << Changed line
        ->selectRaw('SUM(price)')
        ->orderBy('users.name')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix all query including SUM column as far as the duplication seems not fixed on it? And also in case, it will need other SUM colums according to some conditions? like "SUM(case ... else ... end) syntax?

Comment: That's a new question, but I'd guess that your data structure is wrong. Your users have products which have carts. Usually users have carts which have products.